# I have a 16x16 stud clear base plate. Where is it from?

Tags: part-identification

I found another grab bag treasure. I ended up with a 16x16 stud clear(ish) base plate. A quick look at bricklink gave me a *no items found* message. I'd like to know which set(s) this piece can be found in as I have grand plans in mind.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Any of [these three sets](http://www.bricklink.com/catalogItemIn.asp?P=3867&colorID=12&in=A)

(AKA:
6162-1 A World of LEGO Mosaic 4 in 1
6163-1 A World of LEGO Mosaic 9 in 1
852676 Travel Game - Multi Game Pack 9-in-1)

Probably.

Bricklink hint: just search for a size, like "16 x 16". "3x3 plate" is fun too.

Comment: It would be helpful if you provided more than just a link.